# Tabelrow in Tablelayout always shows as 'wrap_content'

Tags: android, tablerow, android-tablelayout

I have empty Tablelayout in xml and adding tablerow programatically.

The row width is always behavies 'wrap_content' am I missing something.

tablelayout  in layout.xml

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000">
            </TableLayout>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Java code:

```
TableLayout mRestable= (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

TextView name_tw = new TextView(this);
name_tw.setTextSize((float) 16.8);
name_tw.setText(aName);
name_tw.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
name_tw.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

if(aValue==null)
{
    name_tw.setBackgroundColor(0xffa09f9f);
    name_tw.setTextSize((float) 17.8);
    name_tw.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER);
    name_tw.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

}

row.addView(name_tw);        


mRestable.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

how to set the row as 'fill_parent'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `HorizontalScrollView`. What do you think, how wide a `match_parent` width child in it would be? `match_parent` in a scroll view is ignored for a reason.

If you want the table to fill the screen horizontally even if it does not need to scroll, set `android:fillViewPort="true"` on the `HorizontalScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please add below code to mark the answer as the complete solution to the question. along with this, textveiw layout_weight=1 should be added  here is the code 'TableRow.LayoutParams _params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
         name_tw.setLayoutParams(_params); 
         name_tw.setTextSize((float) 17.8);'